# Hide IllegalArgumentException in Spring Boot Application log for specific IP Address

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging

we have a spring boot application which gets pen-tested randomly. A lot of times we get errors like:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens
```

thats fine for us these errors happen. We have Ajp and HTTP/HTTPS accessible. And obviously the pentester tries to get somewhere in, and tries whatever possible.

My question now is, could we change the logging behavior so these messages do net get logged for a particular IP Address? These Messages get logged as ERROR so our Nagios is sending emails like crazy.

We do not want to hide these Error messages entirely, just for the pen-tester.

I tried using a doFilter class, but these errors happen before the Filter jumps in.

I don't have any idea where to start knowing the filter do not work...

Thanks in advance